# C++ and boost 1.71 - error: reference to ‘_1’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-propertytree, websocket++

I am using the libraries websocketcpp and boost 1.71. The code used to work with boost 1.58 but after upgrading both libraries, it won't compile. The C++ compiler is g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 and the code is the following:

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::read_json;
using boost::property_tree::write_json;

using websocketpp::connection_hdl;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;
//.......
{
    srv.init_asio();
    srv.set_reuse_addr(true);
    srv.set_open_handler(bind(&WsServer::on_open, this, websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1));
    srv.set_close_handler(bind(&WsServer::on_close, this, websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1));
    srv.set_message_handler(bind(&WsServer::on_message, this, websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1, websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2));
}
```

I sorted out using `#define BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS`. However, that will give the following error:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:319:35: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, boost::property_tree::json_parser::detail::standard_callbacks<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, char>) (
boost::property_tree::json_parser::detail::standard_callbacks<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >&, std::_Placeholder<1>&)’
  319 |         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//...
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:176:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:184:7: note: candidate: ‘R boost::_mfi::mf1<R, T, A1>::operator()(T&, A1) const [with R = void; T = boost::property_tree::json_parser::detail::standard_callbacks<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; A1 = char]’
  184 |     R operator()(T & t, A1 a1) const
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:184:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::_Placeholder<1>’ to ‘char’
  184 |     R operator()(T & t, A1 a1) const
```

Comment: Do you need `using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;` as you are explicit in the given code?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Don't `use` names at a wide scope unless it's central to all the code that can see it, or you risk running into collisions like this.  That is, after all, the whole reason why it's in a namespace in the first place, and `using` subverts that.  When I feel `using` is necessary, I try to keep it local to the smallest possible scopes (like local to functions), even if that means repeating it once or twice in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Like everybody says, don't `using namespace`.

Also, using more recent boost you should avoid `BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS`, and instead of `<boost/bind.hpp>` include `<boost/bind/bind.hpp>` (which no longer does that by default.

This is the source of the conflict you see, since `property_tree` uses boost bind (as the error messages show).

> Completely unrelated: DO NOT (ab)use PropertyTree as if it is a JSON library. Instead use Boost JSON or some other JSON library.

---

> Also, unrelated, you don't need all the `using`s anyway. You can already use ADL to reduce the typing:
>
> ```
> #include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
> #include <iostream>
>
> int main()
> {
>     boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
>     std::istringstream str(R"({"hello":"world"})");
>     read_json(str, pt);
>     write_json(std::cout, pt);
> }
> ```
>
> See [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b0405d3a8c3ab70)

Comment: Added another note on ADL to avoid `using`

Comment: Agreed, PropertyTree is not suitable as a JSON library in a web server. I tried once and I only got hurt.

Comment: Many people have. Property Tree (as the name suggests) is not a JSON library at all.